# Intuition behind upper and lower hemicontinuity

Tags: analysis

I've been studying quite a bit about upper and lower hemicontinuity with reference to correspondences. However im having a hard time seeing the advantage of this definition and what it adds to the overall understanding of continuity in general.

Whats an intuitive way to understand upper and lower hemicontiuity/ Why is it important?